DTR DALI commands: difference between #257 and #163
I want to use DALI commands of DTR. But I got confused with commands #257 and #163. Can anyone tell the difference between these two commands?

Does the documentation for the DALI device(s) you need to communicate with describe the use of these commands?

Command 257 is Set DTR0, Command 163 is Query Power On Level according to IEC 62386-102 using edition 1 command numbers. See these extracts below as definitive:


Edition 2 refers to Opcode bytes but for command numbers 0-255 these are the same as command numbers except expressed in hex format. Command numbers above 255 use the address byte for the command and the opcode byte for data.
DAPC, probably the most commonly used command, doesn't have a command number or a reserved opcode byte, it is distinguished by having the selector bit cleared in the address byte.
